# how to find if a car can drive on hills easily or not?

Tags: automatic-transmission, power

I have a Daihatsu Mira car with 650cc, it has a Turbo Engine with an automatic gearbox. I want to go to a hill station but not sure that this car can drive there easily or not. I want to go to a point where cars with 800cc can easily go.

This car is front wheel drive but in rear wheels I can see a differential which is found in rear wheel drive cars.

Is this car ok for driving to Hill Stations?
Here is the car specs:
http://www.tradecarview.com/specifications/daihatsu/mira_custom/rs_cvt_0.66/37481/

Comment: What do you mean with your second paragraph? If it is front wheel drive there is not going to be a differential for the rear wheels, as there is no transmission to them.

Comment: I dont have the manual of this car but there is rear differential in this car not sure why...

Comment: you can see the image here http://tinypic.com/r/2hgweja/6

Comment: Quite a few of the smaller Daihatsus have a temporary 4wd system, whereby the car is front-wheel-drive most of the time, but with a viscous coupling that causes the rear wheels kick in when the fronts start to lose traction. I would imagine that is the case with this car.

Comment: how to test?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This car will be able to go up and down reasonably steep hills, but it is not a powerful car, and it is definitely not an off road car.

650cc and 800cc engines are considered pretty small, but on hill climb vehicles the gearing can give you a lot of torque which will help you climb steep slopes. This car has gearing set up for city driving, so it isn't going to be ideal.

You say you want to be able to reach places where cars with 800cc engines can get to - well, you will be able to take this to most places where a city car of 800cc could get to.